# How to validate exact length of mobile number using jquery form validator?

Tags: jquery

I want to know that how to validate exact length of mobile number using jquery form validator by using rules  ?

Answer (score -1):

jquery is not nessary for validate string, cause that js can meet your demand.
I don't whether you want to validate phone no from which country, for example, if you want to validate the kind of us phone. regxp is like below
 var re = /^(+1-)?\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$/;
 re.test(${targetString});
if you want to validate phone no from specific country, plz give statement.that's all.

Comment: For saudi arabic country and indian country